# “cloud” or "cloud" - is the quotation mark same?

Tags: quotations

I found two different quotation marks, `"cloud"` and `“cloud”`. What's the difference between these? Should I always use `""` or `“”`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Straight quotes vs. curly quotes in formal writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/straight-quotes-vs-curly-quotes-in-formal-writing) Or [Which is the correct apostrophe to use when typing: quote or backtick?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163480/which-is-the-correct-apostrophe-to-use-when-typing-quote-or-backtick/163490#163490) Note also that some typefaces have highly stylised commas.

Answer (score 2):

The English straight double quotation mark `""` was an invention of the typewriter era.

Because typewriters worked by mechanical devices at that time, the number of keys had to be minimized, so this type of quotation mark was invented as a last resort.

Technically, we don't use typewriters anymore, so there is no key-number restriction and avoid using such quotation marks in normal writing.

Comment: Hello, Fang. Please note (1) that it adds to bloat when duplicate questions are answered (yes, and asked), (2) the quality of the answer at the duplicate, including reasonably  authoritative linked and attributed references.